# Is there a way to open observatory after a program has already started?

Tags: debugging, dart

I started a Dart program and there seems to be an issue with memory usage. I'd like to open [Observatory](https://dart-lang.github.io/observatory/) to investigate but the process was not launched with `--observe`.

Is there a way to launch observatory without restarting the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start Observatory by sending a `SIGQUIT` signal to the process.

See the *Standalone apps from the command line* section of [Getting Started with Observatory](https://dart-lang.github.io/observatory/get-started.html):

> You can also retroactively enable the VM service for a running process on Linux or Mac by sending the process `SIGQUIT` (perhaps you have a long-running server that started misbehaving and you want to investigate why). The process then displays the port that the VM service is bound to on its stdout.

```
$ ps ax | grep dart
<pid> pts/61   Sl+    0:01 dart example.dart
$ kill -s SIGQUIT <pid>
Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:<port>
```